# Billingsley Problem 9.4: Applications of the law of iterated logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Here is question from Billingsley Problems 9.4.

> Let $\{X_n\}_n$ be i.i.d. simple random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Then law of iterated logarithms holds. Set $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. From $$P\bigg(\limsup_{n} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\log\log(n)}} = 1\bigg) = 1$$ and $$P\bigg(\liminf_{n} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\log\log(n)}} = -1\bigg) = 1,$$together with the uniform bounded-ness of the $X_n$, deduce that with probability $1$ the set of limit points of the sequence $$\bigg\{\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\log\log(n)}}\bigg\}$$ is the closed interval from —1 to + 1.

I am not sure where to start. Assumptions tell you where you the smallest and largest the limit can be, but takeng $x \in [-1,1]$, how do I build a sequence of the form $$\{x_k\}_{k} = \bigg\{\frac{S_{n_k}}{\sqrt{2n_k\log\log(n_k)}}\bigg\}_{k}$$ such that $x_k \to x$? Maybe this is not a good way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\phi(n) = \sqrt{2n \log \log n}$. Then for large enough $n$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{S_n}{\phi(n)} - \frac{S_{n-1}}{\phi(n-1)} 
&=& \frac{S_n}{\phi(n)} - \frac{S_{n-1}}{\phi(n)} + \frac{S_{n-1}}{\phi(n)} - \frac{S_{n-1}}{\phi(n-1)} \\
&=& \frac{X_n}{\phi(n)} - \frac{\phi(n)-\phi(n-1)}{\phi(n)}\frac{S_{n-1}}{\phi(n-1)} \\
&\to& 0 \textrm{ as } n \to +\infty,
\end{eqnarray*}
since $X_n/\phi(n) \to 0$, $\phi(n-1) /\phi(n) \to 1$ and $S_{n-1}/\phi(n-1)$ is bounded as $n \to +\infty$.

We conclude with a classical topological argument: if $(u_n)$ is any bounded sequence of real numbers such that $|u_n-u_{n-1}| \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$, then the set of all limit points of $(u_n)$ is the whole interval $[\liminf u_n, \limsup u_n]$.